# Attribute to generate compilerwarning for a method in class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class, where I use the singleton-pattern. The class looks like

```
public class MessageAccess
{
    private static MessageAccess instance;
    public static MessageAccess Instance
    {
        get { return instance ?? (instance = new MessageAccess()); }
    }

    private MessageAccess()
    {

    }

    public void Initialize(string data)
    {
        //...
        isInitialized = true;
    }

    private bool isInitialized;

    public void ReadData1()
    {
        // This Method can always be called
    }

    public void ReadData2()
    {
        // This Method can only be called, if Initialize was called. Otherwise an exception will be thrown
    }
}
```

Is it possible to generate a compiler-warning if the Method `Initialize` is never called

Comment: Not heard of one. I would suggest ReadData2 should throw an InvalidOperationException if called without Initialize being called first. You can then write one or more unit tests to ensure that behaviour persists.

Comment: Ok, sounds like the best way. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I understand your point of view, I don't think such warning would be as handy as you think. I'm afraid .NET framework doesn't cater for this type of warnings for a couple of well defined reasons (please refer to this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/19/why-doesn-t-c-warn-about-unused-methods.aspx).

One might think that the lack of this feature is a missed opportunity, but it's not quite the case. Your class, `MessageAccess`, is public and will be compiled into (let's say) a dll. Even if you had this warning while compiling your dll, you wouldn't want it to appear while compiling some external code using that dll's `Initialize` method (which is also public). You basically can't guarantee that no other code will ever use that method, and this is one of the better reasons not to have this warning.

Answer (score 1):

If the class is not used from outside the assembly, you can make it `internal`. In this case, Code Analysis will generate a warning "Avoid uncalled private code", if the method is not called.

Comment: The class will be called from outside. It's in a baselibrary, which other applications use.